# I want maintain main application session while using editor window with session limit

Tags: java, struts

I have a application with session length set to 15 minutes in `web.xml`.

I am using RTeditor on one screen, in RTeditor the user can enter data continuously for 30 minutes but main application session is going to expire.

The challenge is I want to maintain the main application session while using editor window. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to let the application know that you are still using it, i think a timer would do the trick. Use a timer that sends a dummy request (just calling a servlet/controller that returns anything) when the RTeditor is open every 5-10 min to keep the session alive.

OR to avoid the obvious mistake that can happen (The User might leave the RTeditor screen open without using it and the session would never end), check certain (or all) fields to see if they are dirty every 10 min, if they are dirty, then send the dummy request to extend the session.

Edit: Dont know if there are better ways of handling this, but this is how i would do it. (though i am no expert) :P.. Hope it helps!